# Is it possible to buy songs from itunes through my iOS application using iCloud

Tags: ios4, ios5

I had found some info that " Buying music from the iTunes Store is limited to the iTunes application. You can use a link which will pass the user to iTunes to look at that particular song but they can't buy it from within your application." .... is this right ?. Is it possible to buy songs from itunes through my iOS application using iCloud ?. Please anyone give me  clear idea ......

Comment: possible duplicate of [Purchase music from iTunes store without leaving app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3064179/purchase-music-from-itunes-store-without-leaving-app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app can embed links to iTunes content in the same way that you can from a webpage... and that's the only way you can do it. See the [iTunes Link Maker](http://itunes.apple.com/linkmaker/) for both more information, and the mechanism to make such links.